# IIS: FailedRequestTracing module failed to write buffered events to log file for the request that matched failure definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8.5, web-garden

In my web Site I have enabled Failed Request Tracing log feature and configured it to store log files into
the default folder %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles and I have set some failed request tracing rules.

I have granted write permissions to that folder for application pool identity and I have checked that IIS_IUSRS account has write permissions as well on that folder.

My web site is an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Web Garden configuration (application's pool is set to 4 worker processes).

Log files are correctly stored in the folder but I get continuous warning messages in the event log like below:

> FailedRequestTracing module failed to write buffered events to log
> file for the request that matched failure definition. No logs will be
> generated until this condition is corrected. The problem happened at
> least %1 times in the last %2 minutes. The data is the error.

It seems like the cause is that more than one worker process is trying to create a file log in the same folder so they are conflicting/collisioning when creating the next filename in sequence with a correlative number as explained [here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1158660.aspx?Failed%20Request%20Tracing%20Event%202284) by anilr.

How can I solve this problem in order to avoid warning messages appear constantly in the event log?

Note: I am using IIS 8.5.9600.16384 under Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

This event is logged when FailedRequestTracing module failed to write buffered events to log file for the request that matched failure definition. you can try the following steps to solve the problem.

- Enable tracing access to the log file directory.
- Find the current Failed Request Tracing log file path setting.
- Make sure the configured Failed Request Tracing log file directory exists.
- Make sure the IIS_IUSRS group has permission to write to the log file directory.

More information about this error you can refer to this link: [FailedRequestTracing module failed to write buffered events to log file for the request that matched failure definition](https://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtPages/EventId_2284_Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP_64657.asp).

Comment: Yes, I saw this guide before, and in my case all is correctly configured as explained there. Log file directory exists and IIS_IUSRS has write permissions on it, also log files are currently generated correctly but those warning continue appearing in the event log. I think this is a collision issue between many workers processes accessing to the same log file directory in order to create the log file using as a filename a sequence.

Comment: Did the FR logging stop writing all FR logs or just "some"?

Answer (score 0):

When no FR logs are written for a certain website
(e.g. FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC1), in my case the reason was kinda MS IIS logging routines bug/feature taking effect:

The log files are named like "fr[increasing number].log", created one by one in timeline.

So when ordered by "Date modified", the filenames (number parts) should be rising up.
E.g.
1:00AM - fr000001.log;
1:02AM - fr000002.log

But "sometimes" (for me the reason is not known) the logging mechanism breaks that principle and newer files are written with older DateModified. Maybe just writing log1 takes longer than writing log2.

That situation will block further FR logging.

I wrote a PS script that checks for these inconsistencies and archives/moves them away from the folder.

As soon as that operation is finished (so that filenumbers are rising up alongside with DateModified), new FR logs are getting created again.

One thing to metion: the DateModified inconsistency can be in miliseconds part (not visible in Windows explorer).